# Customer Can't log in and have tried with formkey

Tags: customer, login

Customer Can't log in only if i register a new user it automatically goes to my account.
However if i try to login with a existing user it refreshes the page.

I already tried to insert `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` into the different login.phtml

that didn't work so i tried with `<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" /`>

right below the  tag and that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I came here after having a similar (same?) issue.

**After researching** the problem a bit further it showed that the session was not loaded due to security reasons preventing the session cookie to be set. 

You can find the details in `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien`

It yielded to be a general session login problem. Therefore I strongly suggest to look into solutions relating [admin login problems](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/651-unable-to-login-into-the-magento-backend)
note: question relates older version, resulting in the create-login

Answer (score 0):

Try to override AccountController

```
<?php
require_once("Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php");
class Web_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_CUstomer_AccountController{
public function loginPostAction()
{
// generate form_key if missing or invalid
if (!($formKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key', null)) || $formKey != Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()) {
$this->getRequest()->setParams(array('form_key' =>Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()));
}

//Note*
// rest code is same as from Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only right thing to do here is to jump into a xdebug session and trace the problem.

Hacking any core file, as Marius already said, doesn't fix the problem, only hides it.

Are you sure, the form_key is inserted?
Are you sure it is submitted?
Are you sure, the form key is the abort reason?

Answer (score -2):

After much researching and reading codes, I found that "call_user_func_array" for some reason not working.
Open file
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php
Comment line no : 110 below function
call_user_func_array('session_set_cookie_params', $cookieParams);
If this works then , place the same file in local in same path.
Cheers ;)
http://sarfarazlaghari.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/magento-login-functionality-not-working/

Comment: This is a wrong answer. You should never edit the core code. Even if the problem does not appear after that, it does not solves it. It just hides it.